# The Iwasawa decomposition of $\text{GL}(2,\mathbf R)$

Tags: group-theory

The Iwasawa decomposition of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbf R)$ is

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} r & 0 \\ 0 & 1/r \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&x\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

where $\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} \in SO(2)$, where $\begin{bmatrix} r & 0 \\ 0 & 1/r \end{bmatrix}$ is a squeeze matrix and where $\begin{bmatrix}1&x\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is a shear matrix.

I wish to extend this to $\text{GL}(2,\mathbf R)$. Can I multiply with

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{a} & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{a} \end{bmatrix}
$$

Perhaps this gives $\text{GL}^+(2,\mathbf R)$? If so, I am also okay with that.

Finally, I was wondering what the lie algebra of $\begin{bmatrix} r & 0 \\ 0 & 1/r \end{bmatrix}$ is. And also for $\begin{bmatrix}1&x\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension you are trying for is called $QR$-decomposition: For a matrix $A$, QR-decomposition means, $A=QR$ where $Q$ is a $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix (rotation matrix) and $R$ is a $2 \times 2 $ upper triangular matrix with possibly different non-zero elements along the diagonal. This $QR$ decomposition is obtained by Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. So the matrix $[r,0;0,1/r]$ must be replaced by $[r_1,0;0,r_2]$ (arbitrary diagonal matrix). The last matrix $[1,x;0,1]$ remains the same.

Good luck !

Comment: Would you know the lie algebra of the last matrix [1,x;0,1]?

Comment: Dang. I randomly guessed the matrix of the lie algebra to be x[0,1;0,0] on the first try: $\exp x\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: The lie algebra for the other matrix is simply $\exp \left( r_1 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 &0 \\   \end{bmatrix} + r_2 \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\  0& 1 \end{bmatrix} \right)$

Comment: However, I cannot figure out the lie algebra of this matrix $[r,0;0,1/r]$