# The Lie algebra of 'The Iwasawa decomposition of GL(2,)'?

Tags: matrices

In a previous question ([The Iwasawa decomposition of $\text{GL}(2,\mathbf R)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4663814/the-iwasawa-decomposition-of-textgl2-mathbf-r)), it was noted that the Iwasawa decomposition of GL(2,R) is:

$$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}}_K \underbrace{ \begin{bmatrix} r_1 & 0 \\ 0 & r_2 \end{bmatrix}}_A \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1&x\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}}_N
$$

What is the lie Algebra of each term? Can I write the decomposition as $\exp B \exp C \exp D$, where $K=\exp B$, $A=\exp C$ and $N=\exp D$. What are B, C and D?

Comment: Both $K$ and $N$ are $1$-dimensional, and $A$ is $2$-dimensional and evidently abelian.